# Como finalizar sesion automaticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

Que tal amigos estoy trabajando en un proyecto y tengo esto para cerrar la sesión, pero quisiera implementar [JQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) el problema es que no se como hacerlo, tengo este codigo, el cual me realiza lo siguiente con un sweet alert:

```
var timeout; 
document.onmousemove = function(){ 
    clearTimeout(timeout); 
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        swal({
          title: "Cierre de Sesion Automatica",
          text: "Si deseas salir haz clic en Cerrar Sesion o en Cancel para continuar trabajando",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar Sesion",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + "auth/logout",
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function(resp){
                        window.location.href= base_url;
                    }

                });
            }else{
                window.location.href = base_url + "movimientos/ordenes";
            }

        });
    }, 30000); 
}
```

[image: Esto lo hice con un sweet alert]

Ahora bien hay un codigo que me proporciono @Walter Cordova pero necesitaria que me ayudaran a implementarlo en mi codigo, ya que de igual forma necesito la cuenta regresiva, y luego de eso destruya la sesion.

Este es el codigo de @Walter Cordova el cual funciona muy bien, lo dejo en una caja de JS.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.confirm({
       title: 'Alerta!',
        content: 'La sesión esta por expirar.',
        autoClose: 'logoutUser|10000',
        buttons: {
            logoutUser: {
                text: 'cerrar sesión',
                action: function () {
                    $.alert('La sesión ha expirado');
                    //tu codigo AJAX                    
                }
            },
            cancelar: function () {
                $.alert('cancelado');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Este es mi controlador de la Sesion, y abajo esta la funcion logout que destruye la sesion:

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Usuarios_model");
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata("login")) {
            redirect(base_url()."dashboard");
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view("admin/login");
        }


    }

    public function login(){
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        $res = $this->Usuarios_model->login($username, sha1($password));

        if (!$res) {
            /*$this->session->set_flashdata("error","El usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos");*/
            //redirect(base_url());
            echo "0";
        }
        else{
            $data  = array(
                'id' => $res->id, 
                'nombre' => $res->nombres,
                'rol' => $res->rol_id,
                'login' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            //redirect(base_url()."dashboard");
            echo "1";
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Comment: Usas una sesión de codeigniter o las nativas de php?...no comprendo si necesitas ayuda para destruir la sesión, o solo deseas implementar la cuenta regresiva. Te aconsejaría decidirte solo por una librería, ya sea sweet alert o confirm-js

Comment: Utilizo las de CI:

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation','backend_lib');

Comment: Lo que yo quisiera es que al acabar los 10 segundos hiciera la peticion ajax:

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "auth/logout",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp) {
              window.location.href = base_url;
            }
          });

Comment: Comprendo, ya tienes resuelto lo del método que destruirá las sesión en codeigniter? Es decir: `auth/logout`

Comment: Si asi es, esa funcion es la que destruye la sesion

Comment: La respuesta de @Alberto no soluciona tu problema?

Comment: No, haber como me explico, te acuerdas que tu me diste el codigo que coloque arriba?, ok lo que necesito es al finalizar los 10 segundos, que se ejecute auth/logout

Comment: Pero tomando en cuenta el evento onmousemove

Comment: Ok...ahorita te doy un ejemplo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82810/discussion-between-walter-cordova-and-wilsonicx).

Comment: @WalterCordova Ya coloque la respuesta espero que te sirva a ti tambien, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo pero esa es la solucion definitiva, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

traigo la respuesta a este debate, creo que me complique un poco, pero aca dejo el codigo con la solucion, lo que hace es que cada vez que se mueve el mouse se reinicia el contador todo esto incluyendo clearTimeout, para la demostracion coloquense en el snippet, y mueven el mouse, luego lo dejan estatico, y en 3 segundos aparecera el mensaje.

```js
var base_url = 'fake_url';
var timeout;
document.onmousemove = function(){ 
    clearTimeout(timeout); 
    contadorSesion(); //aqui cargamos la funcion de inactividad
} 

function contadorSesion() {
   timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Alerta de Inactividad!',
            content: 'La sesión esta a punto de expirar.',
            autoClose: 'expirar|10000',//cuanto tiempo necesitamos para cerrar la sess automaticamente
            type: 'red',
            icon: 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin',
            buttons: {
                expirar: {
                    text: 'Cerrar Sesión',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function () {
                        salir();
                    }
                },
                permanecer: function () {
                    contadorSesion(); //reinicia el conteo
                    $.alert('La Sesión ha sido reiniciada!'); //mensaje
                    window.location.href = base_url + "dashboard";
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);//3 segundos para no demorar tanto 
}

function salir() {
    window.location.href = base_url + "auth/logout"; //esta función te saca
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bien, dada tu pregunta yo decidiria usar unicamente [confirm-js](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) o bien [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/), el problema que estas combinando dos librerías que hacen exactamente lo mismo, así que no vería la ventaja de combinarlas.

En el ejemplo que te doy no funcionaran los métodos en php, pero según el código de tu pregunta al llegar a ese método `logout()` la sesión muere efectivamente, solo coloca bien la ruta de ese controlador y ese método.

En tu función:

```js
var timeout;
var base_url = 'fake_url';

document.onmouseout = function(){ 
  contadorSesion(); //aqui cargamos la funcion de inactividad
} 

function contadorSesion() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Alerta de Inactividad!',
            content: 'La Sesión esta a punto de expirar.',
            autoClose: 'expirar|3000',
            type: 'red',
            buttons: {
                expirar: {
                    text: 'Expirar',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function () {
                        salir();
                    }
                },
                permanecer: function () {
                    contadorSesion(); //reinicia el conteo
                    $.alert('Sesión ha sido reiniciada!'); //mensaje
                }
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
}

function salir() {
    window.location.href = base_url + "/logout"; //esta función te saca
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tiene una espera de 10s antes que salga el mensaje

Comment: Listo funciono como esperaba ahora bien, no aplica con el evento onmousemove, como hago que solo cuando este inactivo el sistema, se cierre?

Comment: @WilsonicX para usar el evento [mousemove](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) debemos especificar el área donde se moverá el cursor, un div por ejemplo. lo que veo algo tedioso si lo que quieres es validar todo el sistema, seria mejor directo en el document para que se reinicie cada vez que se refresque la pantalla

Comment: Si en el document estaria bien, ahora bien como lo hago?

Comment: El código que respondí de ejemplo funcionaria bien, lo segmente en funciones por si quieres hacer otro tipo de validaciones pero con esta llamada  `$(function () {
    contadorSesion(); //aqui cargamos la funcion de inactividad
});` y la función carga al recargar el documento, y si te das cuenta las demás funciones reinician esta llamada

Comment: Si eso esta bien, pero a lo que me refiero es a como yo lo tenia en la funcion que coloque al principio, si estaba dentro del sistema no importando que vista fuera, y si estaba interactuando no aparecia el mensaje, pero si dejaba inactivo por el tiempo establecido, si aparecia el mensaje, entonces quisiera hacer eso mismo pero como hacerlo? que me confundo un poco en esta funcion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82809/discussion-between-walter-cordova-and-wilsonicx).

Comment: Te comento que no me gusta esta solución, el evento `onmouseout` ejecutara  `contadorSesion()` cada vez que halla inactividad, y el evento `onmousemove` cada vez que se mueva el cursor en el documento. Si encuentro una solución optima para que uses ese evento editare mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias amigo, en serio te agradezco bastante por tomarte el tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

No está tan difícil, solo es copiar el esquema viejo al nuevo.
Aquí no jalará por que no hay back y reduje el tiempo a 3s. Esperamos y verás como aparece el mensajazo.

Saludos

```js
var timeout;
var base_url = 'fake_url';
document.onmousemove = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Cierre de Sesion Automatica',
      content: 'Si deseas salir haz clic en Cerrar Sesion o en Cancel para continuar trabajando',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "auth/logout",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp) {
              window.location.href = base_url;
            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function() {
          window.location.href = base_url + "movimientos/ordenes";
        },
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

En permanecer, solo hay que cambiar contadorSesion(); por clearTimeout(timeout); para evitar que se dupliquen las ventanas de alerta... o al menos eso fue lo que me paso cuando utilize este codigo y lo solucione haciendo este cambio.

```js
var base_url = 'fake_url';
var timeout;
document.onmousemove = function(){ 
    clearTimeout(timeout); 
    contadorSesion(); //aqui cargamos la funcion de inactividad
} 

function contadorSesion() {
   timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Alerta de Inactividad!',
            content: 'La sesión esta a punto de expirar.',
            autoClose: 'expirar|10000',//cuanto tiempo necesitamos para cerrar la sess automaticamente
            type: 'red',
            icon: 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin',
            buttons: {
                expirar: {
                    text: 'Cerrar Sesión',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function () {
                        salir();
                    }
                },
                permanecer: function () {
                    //contadorSesion(); //reinicia el conteo
                    clearTimeout(timeout); //reinicia el conteo
                    $.alert('La Sesión ha sido reiniciada!'); //mensaje
                    window.location.href = base_url + "dashboard";
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);//3 segundos para no demorar tanto 
}

function salir() {
    window.location.href = base_url + "auth/logout"; //esta función te saca
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```